# How can i load a radiobutton value from a csv into a tkinter Listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, callback

I am trying to load a csv file into my program to be able to import from an external file. i want to display the csv list into my list box on tab 2. however whenever i try to callback for the radio buttons i get a StringVar() error *"TypeError: ‘StringVar’ object is not callable"* .is there a way i can display the radio buttons value,being a string, or do i have to convert the value to an integer.

The callback errors are for the sex, question1, question2 and the question3

```
EfilePath="participants_external.csv"
loadButton = Button(tab2, text="Load From 'participants_external.csv", font = ("Lucida Sans Unicode", 8))
loadButton.place(x=10, y=90)

File= open(EfilePath)
Reader = csv.reader(File)
Data = list(Reader)


def loadButtonCallback():
    fIn=open(EfilePath,'r')
    lines=fIn.readlines()
    participants.clear()
    for i in range(0,len(lines)):
        data=lines[i].split(",")
        if(len(data)<7):
            break
        name=data[0]
        ageStr=data[1]
        age=int(ageStr)
        sex=data[2]
        ethnicityCombo=data[3]
        disabilityCombo=data[4]
        question1=data[5]
        question2=data[6]
        question3=data[7]
        participants.append(Participant(name,age,sex,ethnicity,disability,question1,question2,question3))
    participantsListbox.delete("0","end")
    for s in participants:
        participantsListbox.insert(END,s.getInfo())
    fIn.close()

loadButton.config(command=loadButtonCallback,)
```

Full code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import csv

root=Tk()
root.title("Survey")
root.attributes("-fullscreen", False)
canvas = Canvas(root, width = 1920, height = 825)      
canvas.pack()   
img = PhotoImage(file="bg.png")      
canvas.create_image(20,20, anchor=NW, image=img)   




class Participant:
    def __init__(self, name, age, sex, ethnicity, disability, question1, question2, question3):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
        self.sex=sex
        self.ethnicity=ethnicity
        self.disability=disability
        self.question1=question1
        self.question2=question2
        self.question3=question3
    
    def getInfo(self):
        infoStr = self.name+ "         Aged:"+str(self.age)+ "        "+StringVar(self.sex) + "         Ethnicity:" + str(self.ethnicity) + "         Accessibility:" + str(self.disability) + "         Answer 1:" + str(self.question1) + "         Answer 2:" + str(self.question2) + "         Answer 3:" + str(self.question3)
        return infoStr



participants=[]

for s in participants:
    print(s.getInfo())

#Tab Styles
tab_parent = ttk.Notebook(root)
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_parent)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_parent)
tab_parent.add(tab1, text="Blank Page")
tab_parent.add(tab2, text="Data")
tab_parent.pack(expand=1,fill="both")

#tab 2 list box
#is the main listbox for the participants data for callback
participantsListbox = Listbox(tab2,width=200,height=50, background="SlateGray1", font = ("Lucida Sans Unicode", 15))
participantsListbox.place(x=200, y=10)
participantsListbox.delete("0","end")
for s in participants:
    participantsListbox.insert(END,s.getInfo())


#Title
canvas.create_text(235,50, text = "Singing Sculpture Survey",fill="white" , font = ("Lucida Sans Unicode", 25))

#Name 
nameLabel = Label(canvas,text="Name:", bg="white", width=10, anchor="w", font = ("Lucida Sans Unicode", 12))
nameLabel.place(x=40,y=100)
nameEntry = Entry(canvas,width=20)
nameEntry.place(x=175,y=100)

#Age
ageLabel = Label(canvas,text="Age:", bg="white", width=10, anchor="nw", font = ("Lucida Sans Unicode", 12))
ageLabel.place(x=40,y=150)
ageEntry = Entry(canvas,width=20)
ageEntry.place(x=175,y=150)

#Sex
gender = StringVar()
genderLabel = Label(canvas,text="Gender:", bg="white", font = ("Lucida Sans Unicode", 12))
genderLabel.place(x=40,y=200)
rb1=Radiobutton(canvas,text="Male", bg="SlateGray1", indicatoron = 0, variable=gender, value=" Male ", font = ("Lucida Sans Unicode", 10))
rb1.place(x=40,y=235)
rb2=Radiobutton(canvas,text="Female", bg="SlateGray3", indicatoron = 0, variable=gender, value=" Female ", font = ("Lucida Sans Unicode", 10))
rb2.place(x=100,y=235)


#Ethnicity Combo Box
ethnicity = canvas
ethnicityLabel = Label(canvas,text="Ethnicity:", bg="white", width=10, anchor="w", font = ("Lucida Sans Unicode", 12))
ethnicityLabel.place(x=40,y=275)
ethnicityCombo = ttk.Combobox(ethnicity,
values=[
"White",
"Black",
"Chinese",
"Asian",
"Other"])
ethnicityCombo.place(x=175,y=275)

#Disability Combo box
disability = canvas
disabilityLabel = Label(canvas,text="Accessibility:", bg="white", width=12, anchor="w", font = ("Lucida Sans Unicode", 12))
disabilityLabel.place(x=40,y=325)
disabilityCombo = ttk.Combobox(disability,
values=[
"None",
"Wheelchair",
"With Carer"])
disabilityCombo.place(x=175,y=325)

#Question 1
question1Var = StringVar()
question1VarLabel = Label(canvas,text="Did you enjoy the sculpture?", bg="white", font = ("Lucida Sans Unicode", 12))
question1VarLabel.place(x=40,y=375)
rb3=Radiobutton(canvas,text="Very Enjoyable", bg="SlateGray1", indicatoron = 0, variable=question1Var, value=" Very Enjoyable ", width=15, font = ("Lucida Sans Unicode", 10))
rb3.place(x=40,y=425)
rb4=Radiobutton(canvas,text="Interesting", bg="SlateGray3", indicatoron = 0, variable=question1Var, value=" Interesting ", width=15, font = ("Lucida Sans Unicode", 10))
rb4.place(x=190,y=425)
rb5=Radiobutton(canvas,text="Decent", bg="SlateGray1", indicatoron = 0, variable=question1Var, value=" Decent ", width=15, font = ("Lucida Sans Unicode", 10))
rb5.place(x=340,y=425)
rb6=Radiobutton(canvas,text="Alright", bg="SlateGray3", indicatoron = 0, variable=question1Var, value=" Alright ", width=15, font = ("Lucida Sans Unicode", 10))
rb6.place(x=490,y=425)
rb7=Radiobutton(canvas,text="Un-enjoyable", bg="SlateGray1", indicatoron = 0, variable=question1Var, value=" Un-enjoyable ", width=15, font = ("Lucida Sans Unicode", 10))
rb7.place(x=640,y=425)

#Question 2
question2Var = StringVar()
question2VarLabel = Label(canvas,text="Where you curious how the sculpture worked?", bg="white", font = ("Lucida Sans Unicode", 12))
question2VarLabel.place(x=40,y=475)
rb8=Radiobutton(canvas,text="Yes", bg="SlateGray1", indicatoron = 0, variable=question2Var, value=" Yes ", width=15, font = ("Lucida Sans Unicode", 10))
rb8.place(x=40,y=525)
rb9=Radiobutton(canvas,text="Not Really", bg="SlateGray3", indicatoron = 0, variable=question2Var, value=" Not Really ", width=15, font = ("Lucida Sans Unicode", 10))
rb9.place(x=190,y=525)

#Question 3
question3Var = StringVar()
question3VarLabel = Label(canvas,text="Would you like to understand more about the science behind it?", bg="white", font = ("Lucida Sans Unicode", 12))
question3VarLabel.place(x=40,y=575)
rb10=Radiobutton(canvas,text="Yes", bg="SlateGray1", indicatoron = 0, variable=question3Var, value=" Yes ", width=15, font = ("Lucida Sans Unicode", 10))
rb10.place(x=40,y=625)
rb11=Radiobutton(canvas,text="Not Really", bg="SlateGray3", indicatoron = 0, variable=question3Var, value=" Not Really ", width=15, font = ("Lucida Sans Unicode", 10))
rb11.place(x=190,y=625)

#Submit button
submitButton=Button(canvas, text="   Submit your answers", font = ("Lucida Sans Unicode", 12),width=20,height=2, anchor="w")
submitButton.place(x=40,y=675)


def submitButtonCallback():
    name=nameEntry.get()
    ageStr=ageEntry.get()
    age=int(ageStr)
    sex=gender.get()
    ethnicity=ethnicityCombo.get()
    disability=disabilityCombo.get()
    question1=question1Var.get()
    question2=question2Var.get()
    question3=question3Var.get()
    participants.append(Participant(name,age,sex,ethnicity,disability,question1,question2,question3))
    participantsListbox.delete("0","end")
    for s in participants:
        participantsListbox.insert(END,s.getInfo())
    
submitButton.config(command=submitButtonCallback)

#ability to save and load data to/from csv file
#csv can be converted to either a database document using sql or an excel document
saveButton = Button(tab2, text="Save to External File", font = ("Lucida Sans Unicode", 8))
saveButton.place(x=10, y=50)


filePath="participants_data.csv"

def saveButtonCallback():
    fOut=open(filePath,'w')
    for s in participants:
        data=s.name+","+str(s.age) + ","+str(s.sex) + ","+str(s.ethnicity) + ","+str(s.disability) + ","+str(s.question1) + ","+str(s.question2) + ","+str(s.question3)
        fOut.write(data + "\n")
    fOut.close()

saveButton.config(command=saveButtonCallback)

#Load button
EfilePath="participants_external.csv"
loadButton = Button(tab2, text="Load From 'participants_external.csv", font = ("Lucida Sans Unicode", 8))
loadButton.place(x=10, y=90)

File= open(EfilePath)
Reader = csv.reader(File)
Data = list(Reader)


def loadButtonCallback():
    fIn=open(EfilePath,'r')
    lines=fIn.readlines()
    participants.clear()
    for i in range(0,len(lines)):
        data=lines[i].split(",")
        if(len(data)<7):
            break
        name=data[0]
        ageStr=data[1]
        age=int(ageStr)
        sex=data[2]
        ethnicityCombo=data[3]
        disabilityCombo=data[4]
        question1=data[5]
        question2=data[6]
        question3=data[7]
        participants.append(Participant(name,age,sex,ethnicity,disability,question1,question2,question3))
    participantsListbox.delete("0","end")
    for s in participants:
        participantsListbox.insert(END,s.getInfo())
    fIn.close()

loadButton.config(command=loadButtonCallback,)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to successfully import for the the csv using strings inside the Callback.

```
        name=data[0]
        ageStr=data[1]
        age=int(ageStr)
        sexStr=data[2] 
        sex=(sexStr)
        ethnicityCombo=data[3]
        disabilityCombo=data[4]
        question1Str=data[5]
        question1=(question1Str)
        question2Str=data[6]
        question2=(question2Str)
        question3Str=data[7]
        question3=(question3Str)
```

However now the ethnicity and disability values come out as !Canvas because of them being defined as 'canvas' i did this as a placeholder to see if the load method worked, what can i do to define the ethnicity and disability that wont display the same Callback error.